# The best practice to call multiple functions with similiar logic

Tags: python, function, refactoring

When you have 10-100 functions that take the same parameter and return the same result, which is the best practice to call them? Write f1(), f2() 100 times? Put them on dic or list and iterate? Make a class, but still how to call them from there?

I have 10 functions with number at the end of the name. They take a list and return a new list.

```
def func_1(lst):
    logic
    return new_lst

def func_2(lst):
    logic
    return new_lst
...
def func_10(lst):
    logic
    return new_lst

ls = [SOME DATA] # The list with some data that must be handled by 10 functions

# THE QUESTION IS ABOUT THIS: how to make it more elegant?
lst_1, lst_2, lst_3, lst_4, lst_5, lst_6, lst_7, lst_8, lst_9, lst_10 = func_1(ls) + func_2(ls) + func_3(ls) + func_4(ls) + func_5(ls) + func_6(ls) + func_7(ls) + func_8(ls) + func_9(ls) + func_10(ls)
```

I have a loop solution, but don't know if it's good.

```
ls = 'ABCD'
def func_1(lst):
    new_lst = []
    for s in lst:
        msg = 'Func1 ' + str(s)
        new_lst.append(msg)
    return new_lst
def func_2(lst):
    new_lst = []
    for s in lst:
        msg = 'Func2 ' + str(s)
        new_lst.append(msg)
    return new_lst
# ...
def func_10(lst):
    new_lst = []
    for s in lst:
        msg = 'Func10 ' + str(s)
        new_lst.append(msg)
    return new_lst
x = 10
name_lst = 'lst'
name_func = 'func'
list_to_proceed = 'ls'
dic = {}
for i in range(x):
    lst_name = f'{name_lst}_{str(i+1)}'
    func_name = f'{name_func}_{str(i+1)}({list_to_proceed})'
    dic[lst_name] = eval(func_name)
```

My overall goal is to hand over each function's result (a list) to another function which, based on the content of each of list, should proceed lists. Also, maybe it could be done with some decorators and generators, but couldn't figure it out

Comment: Instead of creating a hundred functions, why not parameterize your function to able cover all of your needs?

Comment: I did that at first, it had the functionality of 4 functions with smart *args ruleset, but as i add new functionality it became too long(180 lines), it was hard to read. When I decided to split it it became that I now have 8 easy to read, but hard to call functions. Hm..